# How to disable auto redirect from HTTP to HTTPS on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, redirect, https

There are a lot of manuals how to **enable** auto redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. But I need to **disable** such redirect (according to this advice [SSL everywhere - all the time](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#ssl)). I use Tomcat 7.x and I need to implement next things:

- All resources are protected (via config in web.xml) [**done**]

  ```
  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Application</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  ```
- When somebody makes a request via HTTP - an error is returned (HTTP status 403 I guess) and there is no any redirect

I tried to remove `redirectPort` in `server.xml` already,

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"/>
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

but it lead to a redirect to 443 port only (but I expected disabled redirect).

So my question is: **how to disable auto redirect from HTTP to HTTPS and return the error?**

Comment: Coincidentally I bumped into a similar issue last week, I removed a HTTPS redirect but it seemed to remain in place no matter what config I changed. It turned out to be some caching in my local Windows, as it worked OK from other PCs and from "wget" on the same PC.  I don't know for sure where the caching happened, but as all local browsers suffered from it, I imagine it was on the windows level. I think I did a `ipconfig /renew` at some point, but unsure if that did the trick. Long story short - try from another PC first.

Comment: Unfortunately the trick failed on my PC!

Comment: Hi Roman, were you able to fix the issue ? I'm having the same issue here, please post the answer if you were successful in solving it. Thanks.

Comment: @Elina No, I couldn't find a way to forbid such redirection. As an option you can disable HTTP port at all (comment/remove connector for 80/8080 port in server.xml)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html):

> redirectPort – If this Connector is supporting non-SSL requests, and a request is received for which a matching  requires SSL transport, Catalina will automatically redirect the request to the port number specified here.

The `redirectPort` indicates only the port, but does not allow / disallow redirect, and if it is not specified, Catalina will redirect to the default https port (i.e. 443).

So check your `web.xml` files (WEB-INF/web.xml and CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml), at the end you may see `security-constraint` with `<web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>` or `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>`. Edit the `HTTPSOnly` to `HTTPSOrHTTP` and the `CONFIDENTIAL` to `NONE`.

Answer (score 4):

Comment out  block in conf/web.xml. Doing that, redirectPort will be ignored.

Comment: Comment out which block?

Comment: <security-constraint> block in your application web.xml

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score -2):

on spring boot's embeded tomcat, set redirect port to 0 wont auto redirect, in my case